# PHP Rename object property while maintaining its position

Tags: php, oop, object

***How can I rename an object property without changing the order?***

**Example object:**

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->k1 = 'k1';
$obj->k2 = 'k2';
$obj->k3 = 'k3';
$obj->k4 = 'k4';
```

**Example rename by creating new property:**

```
$obj->replace = $obj->k3;
unset($obj->k3);
```

**Result:**

```
( k1=>k1, k2=>k2, k4=>k4, replace=>k3 )
```

See the problem?

Simply recreating the object property causes the order to change.

I had a similar issue with arrays and came up with this solution:

**Implemented solution for arrays**

```
function replaceKey(&$array, $find, $replace)
{
    if(array_key_exists($find, $array)){
        $keys = array_keys($array);     
        $i = 0;
        $index = false;
        foreach($array as $k => $v){
            if($find === $k){
                $index = $i;
                break;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        if ($index !== false) {
            $keys[$i] = $replace;
            $array = array_combine($keys, $array);
        }
    }        
}
```

Looking for something similar to this but a function that will work on objects.

Can't seem to find any documentation on object property position indexes.

Comment: If the properties in your object require a particular order you're doing something wrong imho.

Comment: Oh, `$index = array_search($keys, $find, true);` will shorten your code quite a bit :)

Comment: nope that breaks it, it will fail if you have a mixed array with associated keys and integers forinstance ['k1'=>'v1', 'v2', 'k3'=>'v3']

Comment: Regarding `array_search()` .. it should be combined with `array_slice()` to work properly in your particular case.

Comment: Isn't array_search more expensive though? I read somewhere that array_search sorts your array before finding the values. plus adding slice introduces another call. The foreach loop will break once the key is found and apply as little load as possible.

Comment: Where did you read *that*? Actually, you don't need `array_slice()`, it will work with `array_combine()` just fine from what I can tell.

Comment: Read it somewhere on a forum today, could be a lie. array_search does break though. test it yourself with the third comments example.

Comment: I introduced the foreach to fix the problem. array_search ignores index 0 in a mixed array.

Comment: PS. I don't need my variables to be in a specific order right now but am just looking for consistency across my array an object classes. I don't like leaving things to chance. For instance if I traverse through a json object and rename a key that was in a specific order for a reason it might cause unforeseen issues later on.

Comment: Objects in JavaScript don't even guarantee a specific order of properties, so using this code to manipulate a structure that gets encoded as JSON just makes no sense to me.

Comment: Btw, here's [proof](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WCvBpQ) that `array_search()` works fine.

Comment: There are many cases where the order could play a significant role. I just want my functions to do what they say. renameKey, not renameAndDisorganize.

Comment: I agree that maintaining the order could be meaningful for PHP arrays ... but for objects I see no merit at all based on what you have mentioned thus far.

Comment: Thanks, for the link. You are right about array search. Setting it to strict seems to have solved that issue. Was not aware of the strict option. It might be a pointless endeavor but I just don't like surprises. Just wanted to know if it is doable.

Comment: Here is once case where order could possibly be an issue: Lets say I call a function that iterates through an object's variables. Every iteration runs a callback with a reference to the object's property name and data. If the rename function were to be called on the active property and the variable were to be added to the end of the object the callback would trigger a second time on the same property once the pointer gets to the end of the loop.

Comment: A function that iterates an object's properties and expects a certain order is a "Bad Idea (tm)"; if something needs to be iterated, it should be an array first and foremost. Updating an object's property names inside a loop is an even "Worse Idea (tm)".

Comment: I am working on some pretty complex search and replace algorithms that have the ability to crawl through nested objects and arrays simultaneously. I will probably never implement something like the scenario as described, just pointing out that there are edge cases that could lead to unexpected results by moving around properties when your only intent is to rename them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, readd your properties

```
$obj = new YourClass();
$backup = [];
foreach ($obj as $key => $value)
    {
    $backup[$key] = $value;
    unset($obj->$key);
    }
replaceKey($backup, $find, $replace);
foreach ($backup as $key => $value)
    {
    $obj->$key = $value;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that general idea should work. Can't believe I didn't think of it. Think my brain was a bit fried. Will also add check to only change public properties. Will post my function once done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a function for your arrays, why dont you do something like :

```
$array = (array) $obj;
$replacedKeyArray = replaceKey($array);

$newObject = (object) $replacedKeyArray;
```

Comment: That would work but would kind of defeat the purpose of having objects in the first place. Converting an object to an array would also kill its methods.

Comment: @DieterGribnitz Your example shows an anonymous object, though; if you meant regular objects you should say so.

Comment: Then create a static method in your class that would take a raw PHP object and return an object of that class, otherwise it's not doable, even PHP Reflection doesn't have a method for changing the key name.